# Using map function in python

Tags: python

If you have the following code, how exactly is it following the documentation: `map(function, iterable,...)`?

```
x = sorted(map(int, dat[0].split()))
```

Is `int` a function and if so, why isn't it expressed as such?

Comment: I'm assuming you at least get the idea of what `map` is supposed to do when you ask this question. In that case, if you're surprised that `int` is usable as the function argument of `map`, why don't you just try using it as a function of one argument and see what happens? i.e. try typing `int(FOO)` in a Python interpreter for various different kinds of FOO. A little playing around in the interpreter is a very good way to answer these kinds of simple questions, and almost invariably quicker than typing up a question for SO. Then you can ask a more targeted question if you need to afterwards.

Comment: "how exactly is it following the documentation"?  Please provide the documentation that actually confuses you.  We don't know what you've read (or haven't read).  We can't really guess what you mean by this question.  Please **update** it to include a link to the documentation which confuses you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a constructor so it's callable so you can use it with `map`

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? What is it a constructor of?

Comment: Please refer to [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex): The constructors `int()`, `long()`, `float()`, and `complex()` can be used to produce numbers of a specific type.

Answer (score 3):

In your case `dat[0]` is as string, and `split()` generates a list of strings, by splitting the input string at whitespaces.

Eg

```
"1 11".split()
```

returns

```
["1", "11"]
```

The `map` function has two input arguments:

1. The first argument is something *which can be called* (in Python you say it is a *callable*), eg a function. `int` is not realy a function but *such a thing* (Python slang: it is an *object*).
      Eg `int("3")` return `3`. So `int` when applied to a string tries to convert this string to an integer, and gives the integer value back.
2. The second argument is something *you can iterate over*, in your case it is a list.

If you then call the `map` function, the first argument is applied to all elements from the second argument.
So

```
map(int, ["1", "11"])
```

returns

```
[1, 11]
```

If you combine what I explained you understand that

```
map(int, "1 11".split())
```

returns

```
[1, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you ask "why isn't it expressed as such" I suppose you mean, why doesn't it have brackets like a function? The answer is that if you put the brackets in then you get *what the function does* instead of the function itself. Compare what happens when you enter `int()` versus `int`.

Comment: I discover now `int()` returns `0` while in docs `int(x[, base]) -> integer` does not suppose a default value for `x`. Questionable thing...

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But it would be wrong if `int()` didn't produce something of type `int`: `list()` produces a list, `str()` produces a string, `float()` produces a float, and so on. And what other integer apart from `0` could you expect `int()` to produce? Another interesting one is `bool()`, which produces... no, I'll let you guess.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this

```
def map( function, iterable ):
    return ( function(x) for x in iterable )
```

In `x = sorted(map(int, dat[0].split()))`  the function, `int`, is being *named*, not *evaluated*.  This code provides a function object to the `map` function.  The `map` function will evaluate the given function.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of map in the simplest form is:

```
map(func, sequence)
```

It will apply the function "func" on each element of the sequence and return the sequence. Just in case you don't know, int() is a function.

```
>>> int(2.34)
2
>>> int("2")
2
>>> a = ["1", "101", "111"]
>>> map(int, a)
[1, 101, 111]
```

Now, I will give you my implementation of map().

```
>>> for index in range(len(a)):
...     a[index] = int(a[index])
... 
>>> a
[1, 101, 111]
```

If you have understood the concept, let's take a step further. We converted the strings to int using base 10 (which is the default base of int() ). What if you want to convert it using base 2?

```
>>> a = ["1", "101", "111"]
>>> for index in range(len(a)):
...     a[index] = int(a[index], 2) # We have an additional parameter to int()
...     
>>> a
[1, 5, 7]
```

To get the same result using map(), we will use a lambda function

```
>>> a = ["1", "101", "111"]
>>> map(lambda x: int(x, 2), a)
[1, 5, 7]
```